# How to unhide, hidden QGraphicsItem in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt4, qgraphicsview

I am having `QGraphicsView`, which has multiple `QGraphicsItem`'s.
In QGraphicsItem's, I am having few `rectangles` and some `polylines`. Polylines are attached to rectangles.
I have a feature `Hide Rectangle` in which I manually select a few rectangles from view and then on the right mouse button, there is an option like `Hide Rectangles` which calls the function `HideSelectedRectangles()` which hides the selected rectangles.
Its code is :

```
void myClass::HideSelectedRectangles()
{
    foreach(QGraphicsItem* currentItem, scene->selectedItems())
    {
        QGraphicsRectItem* rectItem = qgraphicsitem_cast<QGraphicsRectItem*>(currentItem);
        if(rectItem )
        {
           rectItem ->hide();
           rectItem ->setSelected(true); // In Refresh() scene->selectedItem() does not recognize this flag
        }
    }
}
```

Once Rectangles get hidden, there is a `Refresh` button that expects to bring back all the hidden objects.

```
void myClass::Refresh()
{
    foreach(QGraphicsItem* currentItem, scene->selectedItems())
    {
        QGraphicsRectItem* rectItem = qgraphicsitem_cast<QGraphicsRectItem*>(currentItem);
        if(rectItem)
        {
            rectItem->show();
            //QPen mPen;
            //mPen.setWidth(1);
            //mPen.setColor(QColor("blue"));
            //rectItem->setPen(mPen);
            rectItem->setSelected(false);
        }
    }
}
```

But above code does not work. At `scene->selectedItems()` there is no selected item found.
How to unhide rectangle using `scene->selectedItems()` in Refresh() ?
I do not want to use `scene->items()` in Refresh() as I do not want to iterate over the whole `scene` again and again for the complexity purpose.

Comment: what about storing all selected items to QList and hiding them? You can use the list for showing items later.

Comment: @Abdurahmon Yes. This will also work. But I was suggested to use bool variables as flag and set that flag on item. And then use `scene->setselectedItems()`. Is this possible using flags ?

Comment: @Abdurahmon  If I set flags on items and then use `scene->setselectedItems()` then I think complexity will be `O(n)` and if I use `QList` then complexity will be `O(n * size of QList )`  Please correct me, if I am wrong.

Comment: I got you, but I think you can not change selected flag after hiding it, [source code](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/graphicsview/qgraphicsitem.cpp.html#2799)

Comment: I've tested, if you hide an item, then it'll be automatically removed from `selectedItems` of the scene, so there's nothing to worry about space complexity.

Comment: For you complexity issue, you say that you hide *a few* rectangles that you *manually selected*. I would not worry too much about complexity in your case, plus as  
Abdurahmon said, the selectedItems does not hold your hidden rectangles. Also, if you store your items as QGraphicsRectItem in a Qlist then you don't have to cast them when showing them again.